# Error when integrating "...is not a function, character or symbol"

Tags: r, function, error-handling, syntax-error, numerical-integration

I have this integration that includes a function. I want to integrate over x values 0-39.

```
#parameters
alpha <- 0.86
y <- 70000
t <- 600
u <- 5353.65

get_p <- function(x,y,t,u) {
  (((alpha^alpha) * ((1 - alpha)^(1 - alpha)) * (y - t * x)) / u)^(1 / (1 - alpha))
}

integrate(x * get_p(x,y,t,u),lower = 0,upper = 39)
```

But when I run this code I get the error if I first put x <- 0:

```
Error in match.fun(f) : 
  'x * get_p(x, y, t, u)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

And I get this error if I don't specify x first:

```
Error in match.fun(f) : object 'x' not found
```

x is not supposed to be defined, we are integrating over i!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `integrate()` function needs a proper function as the first parameter, not an expression. You can use an anonymous function with

```
integrate(function(x) {x * get_p(x,y,t,u)},lower = 0, upper = 39)
```

or with the latest lambda syntax

```
integrate(\(x) {x * get_p(x,y,t,u)},lower = 0, upper = 39)
```

Comment: You are too kind :-) .   I really wish there were a "Close_because   never read the man page" option.